# Passing querystring Ids URL Routing using namespace system.web.Routing

Tags: .net, asp.net, url-rewriting, url-routing

I'm new to URL routing.

Case 1: I can implement URL Routing for `URL:/content/category.aspx` mapped to `/Reservation`

Case 2: I'm not quite sure how to handle the query string values.

For example:

```
URL:/content/category.aspx?SID=5&CID=191
```

I want this to map to: `/Reservation`

Code written for Case 1:

**Global.asa**

```
Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub

Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    Dim urlPattern As String
    Dim Reservation As Route
    urlPattern = "Reservation/"
    Reservation = New Route(urlPattern, New JRouteHandler("~/content/category.aspx"))
    RouteTable.Routes.Add("Reservation", New Route("Reservation", New JRouteHandler     ("~/content/category.aspx")))
End Sub
```

**Http Handler**

```
Public Sub New(ByVal virtualPath As String)
    _virtualPath = virtualPath
End Sub

Public Function GetHttpHandler(ByVal requestContext As RequestContext) As IHttpHandler Implements IRouteHandler.GetHttpHandler
    If (Not UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(_virtualPath, requestContext.HttpContext.User, requestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod)) Then
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = CInt(Fix(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized))
        requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End()
    End If

    Dim display = TryCast(BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(_virtualPath, GetType(Page)), name)

    display.pageName = TryCast(requestContext.RouteData.Values("name"), String)
    Return display
End Function
```

---

```
Public Interface name
    Inherits IHttpHandler
    Property pageName() As String

End Interface
```

-In web config

```
</modules>
```

Comment: @OP, please edit and rewrite the last part of the question about web config - it's entirely unclear what your question is.

Comment: i used Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll to rewrite URL.If i run application through ASP.NET development server i can able to achive my routing(http:localhost:1130/reserve/home)If i run application through IIS 5.1 i mgetting HTTP 404 file not found error.

Comment: as this question is not general discussion, this question should not be community Wiki, Plz edit this question and uncheck the community Wiki check box..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it the way you are doing. We have implemented URL Re-Writing with the help of this free third party DLL, you can achieve what you want with the help of this Tool. It can handle query strings as well. What we did was add the DLL into our solution and write rules in the web.config for URL mapping. Please try this and if you need further help let me know. 
http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html

Comment: URL Routing using namespace system.web.Routing : 
how to Pass querystring values

Comment: To handle queryString, I have write rules in web.config like....
<add name="indexModuleLogin" virtualUrl="^~/(.*)/login.aspx" rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" destinationUrl="~/Login.aspx?cc=$1&amp;urw=t" ignoreCase="true"/>
I have used the dll from mention website and follow that website

Comment: used dll and working fine.if try to run web application using IIS i m getting error HTTP 404 file not found.

Comment: this error occur when file not exist physically...
Check the path from URL and make sure you have that file in that location....

Comment: When i run application through VS 2008 working fine.
But when i run same using IIS it is giving this erro

Comment: there must be path problem, plz check ur URL. I can't guess here ur problem. how can i check ur problem... ???